# simulator or test environment for web application

Tags: testing, web-applications, simulator

I am working on a web app that will run only on firefox and on win / linux machine.

I have done that thing and now want to test with various environment like mac, android, opera browser etc.

My query is whether there is any test environment (simulator) available that will allow me to test the app on different platform without testing on real machine?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try with a virtual machine like VirtualBox / VirtualPC / VMWare.

Some Windows versions are available freely as virtual machines images in the Microsoft site.

Not sure for the rest , as you write first

> a web app that will run only on firefox and on win / linux machine.

...but then talk about mac and android.

For android, you could give a try with their [emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).
For Mac OS I am afraid that you won't find legal solutions.